# UIViewController Nib Layout changes at runtime

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

[image]

Notice the Nib on the left displays a layout with 2 UILabels, 1 UITextView and 2 buttons. The Y coordinate of the buttons changes at runtime. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

***Update #1*** - Problem goes away when I shift to a iPhone Retina 4-Inch display.
[image]

***Update #2 SOLVED*** - Problem goes away when by unchecking 'Autolayout' in the xib properties.
[image]

Comment: Could you tell which springs and struts at set in your XIB? It just looks like the buttons are layed out relatively to the bottom of the screen, which makes it look different on a smaller screen.

Comment: The problem goes away when I use the 4-inch simulator. I'm going to add to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using iOS 6 and a storyboard with the 4-inch "tall" iPhone screen form factor simulated. Assuming you are using Auto Layout, you probably have a constraint added to one or both of the buttons that pins them to the bottom of their superview. When you then run your app on the 3.5" screen iPhone simulator, the buttons appear to "move up" as their superview has gotten shorter than on your storyboard.

Find the button with the icon pictured below while editing your storyboard, and click it to toggle the simulated screen size between the 3.5-inch and 4-inch form factors. You should see your buttons re-layout based on their constraints.

[image: Apply Retina 3.5 Form Factor Button]

To set your buttons' spacing relative to the top instead of bottom of their superview, select both buttons and from the menu bar choose the **Editor** menu > **Pin** > **Top Space to Superview**. (Or use the Pin button pictured below directly from the storyboard.)

[image: Pin Button]

There's a good [introductory tutorial to Auto Layout here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2), if you haven't learned about it yet.

Comment: "Editor menu > Pin > Top Space to Superview." crashed xcode first time out!

Comment: That sounds like an Xcode bug :) try it again, maybe with the storyboard button instead of the menu bar?

Comment: The change made now difference. I believe the problem is that my storyboard is set for the 4-inch display and I was testing using the 3.5" iphone simulator. Strange that the layout would be relative. :-(

Comment: Did you try toggling the storyboard simulated form factor to see what happens (using the other button pictured in my post)? You should see the buttons moving there, if the constraints are the issue. Also, try running on the 4-inch simulator and seeing if the layout looks as expected.

Comment: Yes, the layout did NOT change when I toggled. The 4-inch sim works and looks perfect.

Comment: The answer was in the link you posted regarding "Autolayout" - view now works in all resolutions.

Comment: What ended up being the problem then? *Edit:* I see you edited your answer to note that turning Auto Layout off "fixed" the problem. Just note that you are now using the old Autosizing layout system (which existed pre-iOS 6), which is not nearly as capable as Auto Layout (new to iOS 6). If you take some time to learn a bit more about Auto Layout (the link I posted is a great starting point) I bet you can both find out how to fix your layout without turning Auto Layout off, and find out why you should keep using Auto Layout.

Comment: I agree and appreciate the advice. For now, I have one orientation to support for an enterprise app. I'm certain that will change and Auto Layout will be necessary. However, this is exactly why I got away from web development. I can't stand that JS and CSS behave differently across browsers. Feels like that is creeping into the iOS.